# applescript do shell script issue

Tags: shell, applescript

I have a command that produces an output that works in Terminal but not in AppleScript as a 'do shell script'. Essentially the last line of the output is missing in the shell script version.

**Terminal output :-**

```
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
%%SeparationName: Text black
```

**'do shell script' in AppleScript output :-**

```
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
```

Any ideas why the last line is missing?

Code in Applescript is :-

```
set Stage1 to do shell script "gs -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sDEVICE=tiffsep -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -r72 -sOutputFile=/Users/ant/p001 '/Users/ant/Desktop/7savage.pdf'
```

The Stage1 variable holds the output from stdout missing the last line that contains the '%%SeparationName: Text black' part.

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: it look like it might have something to do with th %% how are you collecting the output ? Can we see the actual script ?

Answer (score 0):

The last line is probably printed to stderr. You can redirect stderr to stdout with `2>&1`:

```
do shell script "(echo a>&2)" -- ""
do shell script "(echo a>&2)2>&1" -- "a"
```